# Create pattern to repalace part of timestapms

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with a timestamp that looks like:2020-03-02T20:33:02

I need to remove everything from T in each row.
I tried:

```
for i in CDCn1["Date"]: 
     CDCn1['Date'] = i.str.replace(r'i[9:]', '')
     print(CDCn1)
```

and had to do individually:

```
CDCn2['Date'] = CDCn2['Date'].str.replace(r'T07:13:07', '')
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can use regular expressions: `CDCn2['Date'] = re.sub(r'T.*', '', CDCn2['Date'])`. But your data structure is unclear so it makes it harder to effectively help you. Try to give more details on your data

Comment: That works thanks @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamps are all strings you could use

```
CDCn1['Date']=CDCn1['Date'].str.split('T').str.get(0)
```

This splits the string on the T and then only keeps the first part.